# face map $d_i^n:\Delta^{n-1}\to\Delta^n$

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, function-and-relation-composition, simplex

I have the following formulas about face maps, which I try to proof.

> 1) $d_j^{n+1}d_i^n=[e_0,\dotso, \hat{e_i},\dotso, \hat{e_j},\dotso, e_{n+1}]:\Delta^{n-1}\to\Delta^{n+1}$ for $j>i$.
>
> 2) $d_j^{n+1}d_i^n=[e_0,\dotso,\hat{e_j},\dotso, \hat{e_{i+1}},\dotso, e_{n+1}]:\Delta^{n-1}\to\Delta^{n+1}$ for $j\leq i$
>
> 3) $d_j^{n+1}d_i^n=d_{i+1}^{n+1}d_j^n$ for $j\leq i$

Proof:

Let $(x_0,\dotso, x_{n-1})\in\Delta^{n-1}$. Then is

$d_j^{n+1}(d_i^n(x_0,\dotso, x_{n-1}))=d_j^{n+1}(x_0,\dotso, x_{i-1}, 0,\color{red}{x_i}, x_{i+1},\dotso, x_{n})=(x_0,\dotso, x_{i-1}, 0, \color{red}{x_i},x_{i+1},\dotso, x_{j-1}, 0,\color{red}{x_j}, x_{j+1},\dotso, x_{n+1})$

The second formula can be proven similary, where in the case of $i=j$ the final result is a vector which looks like this:

$(x_0, \dotso, x_{i-1}, 0, 0, x_{i+2},\dotso, x_{n+1})$

Am I right?

The 3rd formula then just follows from the first two.

Thanks in advance.

> Definition: For $0\leq i\leq n-1$ is the $i-th$ face map defined as $d_i^n:\Delta^{n-1}\to\Delta^n$ induced by $[e_0,\dotso, \hat{e_i},\dotso, e_n]:\Delta^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: I think that you ought to include definitions of $d_j^n$.

Comment: @Batominovski I did, I thought the function/notation $d_j^n$ is common.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that other users are going to be familiar with your notations.  In fact, I am wondering if you made a mistake.  Isn't $d_i^n$ the map dropping the $i$-th coordinate?  Then, why does $d_i^n$ send $\Delta^{n-1}$ to $\Delta^n$?  Shouldn't it be the other way around: $d_i^n:\Delta^n\to \Delta^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Batominovski Thats why I am asking this question. I might have done a mistake in my lecture notes, so I tried to proof it myself. I do not think, that $d_i^n$ "drops" the i-th coordinate, but sets it to $0$. But now that I think about it. I guess you are right. So it should be $\Delta^{n+1}\to\Delta^{n-1}$ in the formulas too.

Comment: If it adds a zero, then your notation is not common at all.  Usually the hat notation ($\hat{e}_i$) means the $i$-th coordinate is removed.

Comment: And if the map $d_i^n$ does insert a zero in the $i$-th coordinate, then it is correct that $d_i^n$ maps $\Delta^{n-1}$ to $\Delta^{n}$.  But your work does not use $d_i^n$ correctly.  For example, $$d_i^n(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{n-1})\in \Delta^{n}$$ for all $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\in \Delta^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Batominovski Ok, the hat notation here is supposed to mean, that the i-th coordinate is removed too.

Comment: Then, your question does not make sense.  If you remove an arbitrary coordinate of a simplex, then the resulting point may not lie in a simplex.  For example, with $(x_0,x_1,x_2):=(0,1/2,1/2)\in\Delta^2$, removal of the first coordinate gives you $(x_0,x_2)=(0,1/2)$, which is not in $\Delta^1$ as $x_0+x_2\neq 1$.  Now that I think of it, inserting a zero makes perfect sense, but then the hat notation is out of place.  Perhaps you should ask your lecturer.

Comment: @Batominovski I edited the question now, with corrections in red. Would this be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know now what is happening, and that is why one should declare what notations mean to avoid confusion.  In this answer, I attempt to fix the errors and undefined terms in your question.  As usual, the $k$-dimensional simplex is the set $\Delta^k\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined by
$$\Delta^k:=\Big\{\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{k+1}\,\Big|\,x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\geq 0\text{ and }x_0+x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=1\Big\}\,.$$

First of all, $e_0,e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ are standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (and by abuse of notation, $e_0,e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{n+1}$ are also standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$).  Then, you try to identify $\Delta^{n-1}$ with the convex combination $$\left[e_0,e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{i-1},e_{i+1},e_{i+2},\ldots,e_n\right]=\left[e_0,e_1,\ldots,\hat{e}_i,\ldots,e_n\right]\,.$$
Then, the map $d_i^n:\Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^n$ is defined to be
$$d_i^n\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right):=\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\in \Delta^n$$ for all $\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\in\Delta^{n-1}$.  This means the image of $d_i^n$ is precisely $\left[e_0,e_1,\ldots,\hat{e}_i,\ldots,e_n\right]$. That is, $d_i^n$ is the embedding of $\Delta^{n-1}$ into one $(n-1)$-dimensional face of $\Delta^n$.   (I don't know why you wrote something like $d_j^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}=\left[e_0,e_1,\ldots,\hat{e}_i,\ldots,\hat{e}_j,\ldots,e_{n+1}\right]$.  This makes no sense.  A function does not equal a simplex.)

Hence, it is easy to check all the statements.  Let $\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)$ be an arbitrary point of $\Delta^{n-1}$.

Now, we shall deal with Part (1).  For $j>i$, 
$$\begin{align}\left(d_{j}^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}\right)\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)&=d_j^{n+1}\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n\right)\\&=\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_i,\ldots,x_{j-2},0,x_{j-1},x_j,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\end{align}$$
has zeros in the $i$-th and $j$-th coordinates.  That is, $d_j^{n+1}\circ d_{i}^{n}:\Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^{n+1}$ satisfies $$\text{im}\left(d_j^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}\right)=\left[e_0,e_1,\ldots,\hat{e}_i,\ldots,\hat{e}_j,\ldots,e_{n+1}\right]\,,$$
as required.

Next, we tackle Part (2).  For $j\leq i$,
$$\begin{align}\left(d_{j}^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}\right)\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)&=d_j^{n+1}\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n\right)\\&=\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},0,x_j,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_{i},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\end{align}$$
has zeros in the $j$-th and $(i+1)$-st coordinates.  That is, $d_j^{n+1}\circ d_{i}^{n}:\Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^{n+1}$ satisfies $$\text{im}\left(d_j^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}\right)=[e_0,e_1,\ldots,\hat{e}_j,\ldots,\hat{e}_{i+1},\ldots,e_{n+1}]\,.$$

Finally, we justify the equality in Part (3).  For $j\leq i$, we see that, $j<i+1$.  Therefore, from Part (1),
$d_{i+1}^{n+1}\circ d_j^{n}:\Delta^{n-1}\to\Delta^{n+1}$ satisfies $$\text{im}\left(d_{i+1}^{n+1}\circ d_j^{n}\right)=[e_0,e_1,\ldots,\hat{e}_j,\ldots,\hat{e}_{i+1},\ldots,e_{n+1}]=\text{im}\left(d_j^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}\right)\,.$$  Additionally,
$$\begin{align}\left(d_{i+1}^{n+1}\circ d_j^{n}\right)\left(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)&=\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},0,x_j,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_{i},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\\&=\left(d_{j}^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n})(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\end{align}$$
also by Part (1).  This proves that $d_{i+1}^{n+1}\circ d_j^{n}=d_{j}^{n+1}\circ d_i^{n}$.

Comment: I'm confused with your proof that, for example, in part (1): $d_i^{n-1}$ is supposed to act on $(x_0, ... , x_{n-2})$, but you apply $d_{j}^n\circ d_i^{n-1}$ to $(x_0, ... , x_{n-1})$, isn't this wrong?

Comment: @JiangnanYu  Thanks for pointing that out.  I messed up the superscripts a little bit.  I hope everything is fixed now.